# ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom and Primeng. Not all styles are presented

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I use table Primeng datatable and there is a need to implement filter for columns.

Problem is that I enabled ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom but no styles are presented for filters it's like there is no css at all. But for table there are styles as you can see
in my history-changes.component.css I imported styles.

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

ViewEncapsulation in my ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-history-changes',
  templateUrl: './history-changes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./history-changes.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
```

[image]

By the way filters work. Just problem with absence of styles for it.

Screenshot with the error :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

because inside shadowDom everything is encapsulated, so you need to append CSS into your component Shadow Root. This is what I'm doing, it's working fine:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.scss',
    "../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
    "../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

Note that global styles (which you write in `styles.scss`) or you do `@import` inside your `component.scss` they both won't work, here we need `inline style`, meanwhile `@import` will import style from URL (or path). Putting them in `styleUrls` does the job, cuz at build time Angular will read your style and import it inline with your component

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did as you wrote. unfortunately same behavior, by the way there is ( and was) error => ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: for the error with "getComputedStyle". check my package here, it fixes that issue: https://github.com/maitrungduc1410/primeng-shadowdom-directives

Comment: for styling issue, I don't know why it doesn't work in your end, in my company we're doing this way and it's working really fine :). We have a big project written in Angular + PrimeNg needs to exports as Angular Element, later on we put it as a part of a Web Component project, they're all displaying well

Comment: Thank you once again, I'm glad that there are such persons as you that thrive to help. I don't know whay it does not work with styles. And about your package, If you have time perhaps you will write something for <p-columnFilter type> element?